# Php-intl installation on XAMPP for Mac Lion 10.8

Tags: php, xampp, osx-lion, intl

Hi folks i am trying to install intl library on xampp for mac. I have installed php 5.3, so i just copied intl.so file from the php 5.3 location to Xampp bin folder. After that i uncommented extension=intl.so and restarted the server. Still i dont see intl updated in the phpinfo() (Getting error Class Locale not found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran this in Terminal.

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

Then just add

```
extension=intl.so
```

to `php.ini`.

Comment: sudo: pecl: command not found i am not getting any other way to install intl extension kindly help

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked (php 7.1, MAMP, macOS Mojave):

Downloaded the intl.so file from `https://github.com/skmedia/php-extensions-mamp/blob/master/php-5.4.4/intl.so` and copy it to `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`