# Php-intl installation on XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, apache, cakephp

I need to use the extension intl on my mac with XAMPP.

So  I have followed this links:

[Php-intl installation on XAMPP for Mac Lion 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391284/php-intl-installation-on-xampp-for-mac-lion-10-8)

http://lvarayut.blogspot.it/2013/09/installing-intl-extension-in-xampp.html

I restart always my apache server but isn't installed the extension. Because if I launch:

```
php -m | grep intl #should return 'intl'
```

return empty

The command that I can't launch without it is for composer and cakephp like this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist -s dev cakephp/app cakephp3
```

Return me this error:

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/bake dev-master requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for cakephp/bake dev-master -> satisfiable by cakephp/bake[dev-master].
```

So I need to solve the problem of ext-intl with the extension intl.

Can someone help me with this problem?
How can I install this extension?

Thanks

Comment: To set path for MAMP
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path and it's also automatic

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These below steps helped me, Just in case if you are using OSX

Steps from http://www.phpzce.com/blog/view/15/installing-intl-package-on-your-mac-with-xampp

1. Check which php path is set i.e.

   ```
   root$: which php
   ```
2. If you are using xampp on your mac it should be

   ```
   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php
   ```

   but if its

   ```
   /usr/bin/php
   ```

   you need to change your OSx php

   ```
   root$: PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
3. Install icu4c

   ```
   root$: brew install icu4c
   ```
4. Install Intl via PECL

   ```
   root$: sudo pecl update-channels 
   root$: sudo pecl install intl
   ```
5. You can check if Intl was installed successfully

   ```
   root$: php -m | grep intl #should return 'intl'
   ```

Done

============================

Note:

- From extensions list in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` file Add / Uncomment `extension=intl.so` line. And restart Apache. Thanks @pazhyn
- Before installing "intl" you have to install Autoconf if you have not installed it. Thanks @Digant

  - via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) brew install autoconf automake
    or
  - by running below commands

    ```
    curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
    tar xzf autoconf-latest.tar.gz
    cd autoconf-*
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
    make
    sudo make install
    cd ..
    rm -r autoconf-*
    ```

Comment: Amazing, it's work fine, but some steps have details inside, like install PECL and path of icu4c

Comment: getting 'No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl" '

Comment: when i run this command  sudo pecl install intl   it  returns this msg No releases available for package  "pecl.php.net/intl"
install failed   @Belalmazlom

Comment: You will also need to add `extension=intl.so` into your /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini file and restart Apache.

Comment: Before you install intl you have to install Autoconf if you don’t have installed it yet. In your terminal execute following commands:

cd ~ && curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz 
tar -zxvf autoconf-latest.tar.gz 
cd autoconf-2.69 
./configure 
make 
sudo make install

Comment: Thanks. This worked for XAMPP PHP 5.6 versions but does not work for PHP 7. It gives error "fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found"

Comment: I got it to work for PHP7.1 with Xampp. http://blog.dhawalmehta.com/2019/08/20/install-intl-php-extension-for-xampp-and-magento-for-macos-mojave/

Comment: Anyone managed to get intl installed on mac OS Catalina? I'm getting the following error after I attempt to install intl from pecl: fatal error: 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found

Comment: @ThomasGatt I am getting the same error 'unicode/ubrk.h' file not found.
Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 14):

I had issues with intl when using Moodle, which I fixed by doing the following:

1. Re-run the XAMPP installer ([if you don't have the installer on hand, download it from here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)) and tick the "XAMPP Developer Files" [image: XAMPP installer]
2. Use your terminal and go into XAMPP's binary folder `$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/bin`
3. Use PHP's package manager to install `intl` by running `$ sudo ./pecl install intl` This should compile some things, and if successful, the installation should complete with:

   ```
   Build process completed successfully
   Installing '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so'
   install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/intl-3.0.0
   configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
   You should add "extension=intl.so" to php.ini
   ```
4. `$ cd ../etc` There you will have your `php.ini` to which you have to add `extension=intl.so` On my system I appended the line after line 959, which you can find by searching for `php_intl`
5. Finally restart your Apache web server from the XAMPP GUI.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: this asks for, where the icu librarie should be installed

Comment: when i run this command sudo ./pecl install intl it returns this msg No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl" install failed

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with XAMPP.
I tried several answers but without success.
Could solve lowering an alternative library http://php-osx.liip.ch/.
This library php, comes already installed intl and several other package.
After downloading went to httpd.conf in xampp and LoadModule php5_module pointed to these packages in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so

Comment: could be a solution, I'll try as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: I've just tried this - it worked! Thanks! I also had to add /usr/local/php5/bin to the front of the PATH variable. Once I'd done that, it all seemed to go ok. I've been trying all sorts of things for 2 days now, and this seems to have cracked it for me!

Comment: Finally, after a lot of searching through internet this post has solved my problem, Thanks Leandro Souza Araujo and Sharon... i have used /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so instead of libphp5.so..and Added: export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:${PATH}" in .bash_profile.

Comment: finally, found a solution that works, been cracking my head for hours now, been jumping from builtin apache to brew then xampp.. but not 100% working for me.. I just needed the intl.so file so I just put this file: /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/intl.so into the php.ini problem solved. thanks