# Installing with Composer - php extensions: ext-mcrypt * and ext-intl * missing from your system on XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, magento, composer-php

I've been trying to install Magento 2. I did load everything and with the last commands "composer update" or "composer install" I'm having problem.

```
Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system.
```

The thing is I'm not a pro Mac user or anything so it's very complicated for me to understand what I need to do to resolve this.
I saw a topic here at stackoverflow with the same problem but in that case they were using MAMP. I'm using XAMPP. They were telling to override PHP with MAMP's PHP with the .bash_profile file. I tried the same - didn't quite understand what I was doing.

So please, can anyone help me with solving ext-mcrypt and ext-intl stuff? I don't even know how to find out if they are missin or not.

Thanks!

Here's what in place of mcrypt

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

**FINAL NOTES:**

I marked answer as correct as it resolved my issue with mcrypt with the link from [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension#answer-16832214) next I had issue with ext-intl and to resolve this please follow these links: http://codingexplained.com/operating-systems/mac/installing-php-intl-extension-os-x-mavericks and [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp)

I did write an [article](http://mrgott.com/misc/10-install-mcrypt-and-intl-php-extensions-on-mac-os-x-and-xampp) about these issues and solution. hopefully this helps too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this answer [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension#answer-16832214) and [the following one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension#answer-17192458).

If mcrypt is not enabled open your `php.ini` (see my first answer link above how to find it) and search for

```
;extension=php_mcrypt.so
```

then remove the `;` from the beginning of that line. Same procedure for the other extension.

Comment: do you mean that php.ini should be located in MacintoshHD -> etc?  this etc folder is by default hidden. If it's the right place then, I don't have php.ini, there's php.ini.default

Comment: no I meant you to look up where your Loaded Configuration File (`php.ini`) is located. You get this with `php --ini`. There you can activate the extension.

Comment: Ok got it, but there's nothing like ;extension=php_mcrypt.so, take a look at my question I edited it with the contents.

Comment: you should try the second link then I think.

Comment: Ok I think I'm halfway there, I tried to run composer again, now I have only 1 problem ext-intl problem, so Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. This one still remains. Any ideas? I did try to uncomment it in php.ini but then there was an error with -  couldn't load .dll file

Comment: I think I just managed to install INTL extension. If it works I'll add links to my questions and will mark @Peh answer as correct for mcrypt part.

Comment: yes `.dll` is for windows only. Run `php -i | grep extension_dir` in terminal. Then look in that directory how your extension is named. Or try `extension=intl.so` should be correct for mac.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have INTL installed, and I tried extension=intl.so too. Didn't work. I downloaded it and installed the AutoConf smth. Will share the links in the question.

Answer (score 2):

On linux I:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt ;
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

Answer (score 0):

Following things you can check -

- **Apache Version:** 2.2 or 2.4 and Enable: mod_rewrite.mod_rewrite enables the server to perform URL rewriting.
- **PHP:** 5.4.x where x = 11 or later  5.5.x and
- **Enable PHP Extension:** PDO/MySQL,mbstring, mcrypt, mhash, simplexml, curl, gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both soap and
- add xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000; at php.ini
- **MySQL Version :** 5.6.x and upper

For more info please have a look at this URL -

> http://magentostriker.blogspot.in/2015/03/magento-2-installation.html

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux and PHP 7.0 you would use something like this:

```
yum install php70u-intl
```

I have PHP version 70u in the above example. Bu this will provide "ext-intl".