# Magento - PHP extension intl* missing

Tags: magento, php-7, intl

tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404183/5625013) method

but says

> "No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl" install failed"

tried with

> pecl -vvv install intl

returns this

> Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in
>   PEAR/Downloader/Package.php on line 1511
>
> Warning: is_file(): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in
>   PEAR/Downloader/Package.php on line 1521
>
> Warning: is_file(): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in
>   PEAR/Downloader/Package.php on line 1521
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   PEAR/REST.php on line 432
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in PEAR/REST.php on line
>   432
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://pecl.php.net:443
>   (Unknown error) in PEAR/REST.php on line 432 No releases available for
>   package "pecl.php.net/intl" Cannot initialize
>   'channel://pecl.php.net/intl', invalid or missing package file Package
>   "channel://pecl.php.net/intl" is not valid install

now i don't know what to do, and what this means. please help.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP version 5.3 the extension intl is bundled with PHP.
So what you need to so is just enable the extension for that

- open your php.ini file
- find for ;extension=php_intl.dll
- remove the comment ;

That’s all, restart the Magento2 installation and have fun.

Reference: http://www.magentogeek.com/magento2-intl-php-extension-missing/

Comment: i am using mac, so .dll is no use. sorry , forgot to mention that earlier