# Install PHP intl extension on MacOS

Tags: php, macos, xampp, php-extension

I am facing some issues in the installation of Cakephp. I hope any one had faced the same issue.

**The error**

```
- cakephp/cakephp 3.3.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
```

As per the error message, I removed ; from php.ini file but still getting the same error.

I have Mac 10.12 Sierra, Xampp 5.6.28-1 version and PHP 5.6.24 version.

Comment: You can use MAMP... there it's included. Perhaps you can enable the intl extension in your php.ini?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try MAMP however I enabled all intl extension in php ini file in Xampp.

Comment: These steps may help from a previously asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp)

Answer (score 8):

1. Install the php5-intl extension `brew install php56-intl`
2. If you get `No available formula for php56-intl` do `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php`
3. Restart Apache `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: if we are using macOS HIgh Sierra version 10.13.6 the above steps will not run and give Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: brew tap homebrew/homebrew-core

Answer (score 6):

`intl` is installed by default on `php7.1` with `brew`.

If you already have `php7.1`, you might want to uninstall it first:

```
brew uninstall php71
```

Then install it with pear:

```
brew install php71 --with-pear
```

Then force the links:

```
brew link php@7.1 --force
```

Comment: This solution worked great for me. I was getting errors about missing `ext-intl` with the default PHP that comes with High Sierra. I ran these three commands (which I've read people talk about before, replacing the default PHP). I now think that is a great idea. Doing so upgraded my PHP version from 7.1.16 to 7.1.23 and changed my config folder to `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini`. After, `php --ini` is a helpful command to run.

Comment: It seems to create a weird scene in High Sierra if you start with a virgin Macbook and do `brew install nginx` and then setup your `nginx.conf` file. I swear that built-in PHP just doesn't work reliably and produces hard to trace symptoms. It was having trouble for me also trying to enable `extension=snappy` via `brew install snappy`. In my opinion, blow that garbage PHP off your machine and do the steps described in this answer by *pl-94*.

Comment: The first warning sign is that `intl` comes with the built-in PHP and doesn't work. I installed `php71` from brew and didn't even have to manually enable `ext-intl`, it just worked. You could imagine how a person could get trolled when it comes with the built-in, giving you a false sense of confidence that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AMMPS](http://www.ampps.com). It has a lot great features and you can easily change PHP extensions:

[image]

Comment: I tried installing ammps but the .dmg file does not open.

Answer (score -8):

1 Make sure remove # from your php.ini file:

```
$extension=ext/php_intl.dll
```

2 If you have already enabled intl,add the path to environment and restart

3 Install by brew .

```
$brew install icu4c 
$sudo pecl install 
$intl php -m | grep intl
```

Comment: I did uncomment the ext/php_intl.dll but still I a getting this error

Comment: dll files are for windows. For Mac OS X, it's .so file. By default, php-intl.so will be enabled in php.ini, so no need to change anything.

Comment: This solution is works only with Windows machine