# Error install CodeIgniter 4 - Require ext-intl

Tags: php, xampp, intl

I use macOS BigSur operating system and have PHP 8.0.8 in XAMPP installed.
When I want to download CodeIgniter 4 using composer, an error message appears in my terminal like this:

> Problem 1
> - codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.1.3] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
> - Root composer.json requires codeigniter4/framework ^4 -> satisfiable by codeigniter4/framework[4.0.0, ..., v4.1.3]

I've tried to see the list of extensions in php by `php -m` or `php -m | grep intl` but the result is no intl, then I try to see with `phpinfo()` through the browser the result is still the same no intl, but json is there.

Then I try to remove the semicolon in the php.ini file for the

> intl extension

and I restart apache the error is still there.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share more details. There are a lot of questions covering this, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085083/install-php-intl-extension-on-macos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012363/install-php-7-0-internationalization-extension-intl-on-xampp-on-mac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install PHP intl extension on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085083/install-php-intl-extension-on-macos)

Comment: for Nico Haase:

I've tried that method but got an error at the end like this:
2 errors generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: for Justinas:

I don't use brew, i complety use XAMPP

Comment: for Justinas: that method not work for me, i still get error when I download code igniter