# Magento says INTL is not installed, but php -m shows that it is there

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento2

I am using XAMPP to set up Magento, and I installed the intl extension on my mac. When I run php -m, intl shows up as one of the modules, but Magento still says that it is missing. My php.ini file does have intl enabled and my php version is 5.6. I'm not sure how to proceed and can't find any other questions that solve this problem.

Comment: Try `phpinfo()` (in a php file, executed via browser) instead of `php -m`. Those are different environments with different settings and potentially even different versions of PHP.

Comment: intl doesn't show up in phpinfo(), what am I missing? @Pharaoh

Comment: That depends on your setup. First check the documentation about how to install and enable the module, and then compare it to your configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp)