# Your version of PHP does NOT have the intl extension loaded

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to install cakephp on my localhost using oven.php.
When running the knob i get the error:"Your version of PHP does NOT have the intl extension loaded"

I have uncommented "extension=php_intl.dll" in php.ini  restarted the server in xampp cpanel. i use mac osx high sierra.

Nothing worked

Comment: there is an extra dot at the end of file name

Comment: @Zoha did you mean after oven.php? I think that is a period to end the sentence, not part of the file name.

Comment: @Screwtape007: Can You confirm it is enabled in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Please check [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp) It will help you

Comment: OSX doesn't use `.dll` files, but `.so` ones.

Comment: @tarikul05 i followed your instructions - as it turned out i had to first install 'homebrew' - everything installed successfull; ic4c etc. What failed to install was the last bit:  

sudo pecl install intl
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"
install failed

Comment: even followed the instructions under Note:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp

Still oven.php fails at the "Your version of PHP does NOT have the intl extension loaded"