# Initialize the Cake Project

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to initialize the cakePHP project on Mac and getting the bellow error:

```
Installing cakephp/app (3.7.1)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.7.1): Loading from cache
Created project in firstCake
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.7.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 3.7.4, 3.7.5, 3.7.6].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php-intl installation on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp)

Comment: maybee you want try with this https://github.com/salines/vagrant-cakephp