# How to enable the intl extension in MacOS XAMPP ( PHP Version 7.4.14 )

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, xampp

I am using XAMPP ( PHP Version 7.4.14 ) on macOS Big Sur (ver 11.2.1 (20D74)).

Note : I used XAMPP installer instead of VM.

I installed cakePHP 4 and got this error.

- cakephp/cakephp[4.2.0, ..., 4.2.3] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

In php.in i can see ;extension=php_intl.dll is commented but its for Windows Extensions.

I already search many answer and tired "brew" command but still its not working.

How to install intl in macOS for xampp.

Thanks

Comment: There's another SO question about it, maybe the answer will help you (keep in mind, different macOS version though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp

Comment: @Hoargarth I already tired. not workign

Comment: Any errors you get?