# Trouble Installing CakePHP on XAMPP Mac

Tags: php, macos, cakephp

So I've been trying to install Cake on a Mac laptop running Xampp.  So far I have been unsuccessful.  When I try to create a project, it just returns this->

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4].
```

I have installed icu4c and it says intl is installed on phpinfo.php, but this error message keeps showing up.  I have been working on this for about 4 hours.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and forget xampp and use Vagrant with an Ubuntu box or similar. Much more adaptable and because you  can run multiple boxes with different configurations you more easily have a choice of php versions, databases, frameworks, etc

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391284/php-intl-installation-on-xampp-for-mac-lion-10-8)

Comment: My main built computer is running Ubuntu with Cake no prob.  But this mac has a firmware password so I can't really do anything.

Comment: The issue is that on a Mac, the CLI php is different than the php that Xampp supplies. Without using something like HomeBrew, it can be very difficult to install the correct php extensions. What you can do is run composer with the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option to at least get it installed.

Comment: i  was with same problem and I used `--ignore-platform-reqs`, like:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs cakephp/app <app name>`

Answer (score 2):

i installed cakePHP3 on osx by following the instructions:

open php.ini file in xmapp, the file should be located in "xampp->etc" folder. Edit this file, first find ";extension=php_intl.dll" line and change it to "extension=php_intl.dll" remove ';'. Hope this will help.
let me know what error you are getting if installtion is failing.